# Where exactly earth current flows-SMPS/DC-DC and DC-AC

Tags: current, noise, emc, earth, leakage-current

Ashamed to ask this question after having lot of experience in Converter designs. i always heard and learnt from Sr. Mentors that For better EMI performance we need to give path for conducted noise(and leakage currents) to flow, in this case its Earth ground (P.E). and yes i take care of this in my designs. But never though or understood where exactly this noise will flow. Will it flow into magical Earth? or will it go back to distribution center.
I see people sticking copper rod into earth (with salt and coal etc) and call it earth and connect protective earth (P.E) from their home to this copper ROD. Will earth accepts any electrons pushed to it? doesnt makes sense. where exactly all this H.F conducted noise go (or leakage currents)
[image]
***::--- Please dont take me as rude but do not reply if you are just learner or one who didnt understood it well , just to avoid multiple false response which could confuse new learners. i am expecting answer from some one who is expert in this field by his profession or studies--:***

Comment: It's a great question. Indeed people usually talk in slogans not understanding what the slogans are about. To answer your question a system description is required. It all depends on the architecture. It's different for automotive (massive GND on the car chassis), industrial (big sys, no actual common negative for DC supplies, but common grounding on chassis) and so on.

Comment: Your question really is great. Current flows through the smallest resistance.
https://earthinginstitute.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/misinformation-about-earthing-and-ground-currents.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity)

Comment: I cannot answer your whole question but a part of the question. The ground is having a very large accumulation of charge like the sea has water. As from sea we can both take and give water in the same way we can take and give charge from the earth.

Comment: The current will only flow to earth if there is an AC or DC loop that can take current. Given that you haven't exactly drawn anything that can be analysed, it's pretty hard to help any further.

Comment: Understood, i will add something as example to discuss

Comment: Added detailed illustrative image, hope this helps